# Datatable- converting string to date type filter error

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have 5 columns in my table, the second being a string that acts as a date type (12 Jan 14), so when it filters, it only filters based on the the day rather than year, then month, then day. Keep in mind, I can't change the type to date as this is part of a larger project.

I'm using datatables.net and new to it so any help would be appreciated, so my question being can someone convert the string to a date type and filter?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

var mSortingString = [];
var disableSortingColumn = 4; 
mSortingString.push({ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [disableSortingColumn] });

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table').dataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": false,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "orderMulti": false,
                "aoColumnDefs": mSortingString              
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I think you'll have to add an hidden column to the table which contains the value as a date, you can use it to sort when the displayed date column is clicked

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add link - [https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Sorting Plugins](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/) to see if you find one that you can use. Or, you can create your own sorting plugin, I've done this a few times and is easy.

```
var months = {Jan:1,Feb:2,Mar:3,Apr:4,May:5,Jun:6,Jul:7,Aug:8,Sep:9,Oct:10,Nov:11,Dec:12};
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "my-date-pre": function(a) {
        //12 Jan 14
        var myDate = a.split(' ');
        return (myDate[2] + months[myDate[1]] + myDate[0]) * 1;
    },
    "my-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "my-date-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

so, you can use `sType` in your `aoColumns` or `columnDefs` configurations and set it to **`my-date`**, something like this

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
        { type: 'my-date', targets: 0 }
    ]
 } );
```

where targets are the index of the column with the date starting from 0.